# Set Navigation View Controller title from prior View Controller depending on button pressed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, title

Fairly new to iOS development.

I have a ViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller.

In this ViewController I have two buttons (buttonOne and buttonTwo)  which when pressed push to another view controller (ExerciseViewController).

The problem which i am facing is changing the title of the ExerciseViewController depending on which button is pressed.

So if buttonOne is pressed then title of ExerciseViewController is to be set to One.

if buttonTwo is pressed then title of ExerciseViewController is to be set to Two.

both view controllers have their own seperate classes.

..

ViewController.h - ViewController.m - 
ExerciseViewController.h - ExerciseViewController.m

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Show the code where you push the view controller. Are you setting the title? Show that too...

Comment: It is pushed through storyboard.. title of the ExerciseViewController is left blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` in your `ViewController`. It will be called and provide the triggering button. If you set a tag on the button or check which instance it is to decide what the title should be. Then you can set the title on the seque `destinationViewController`.

In your XIB, you can set the tag of the buttons to '1', and '2'. Or, in your `viewDidLoad` you can do:

```
self.buttonOne.tag = 1;
self.buttonTwo.tag = 2;
```

Then in `prepareForSegue` you can do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"])
    {
        NSInteger tag = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        certViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;      
        destViewController.title = (tag == 1 ? @"One" : @"Two");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive implemented a prepareForSegue:sender in ViewController. How would I go about setting the tag for the button? Will it be set in a buttonPressed method...and how can i read this tag in the prepareForSegue

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        (GET INFORMATION ON WHICH BUTTON PRESSED)
        certViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.buttonName = [(SEND BUTTON PRESSED INFORMATION INTO VARIABLE buttonName];
    }
}

Comment: code is good but receive an error stating (Property "tag" not found on object of type '__strong id' ... I have synthesised and declared property as @property (nonatomic)  NSInteger *tag; still error raised.

Comment: The sender should be a button. And you certainly don't want to create a property like that (integer pointer)...

Comment: Thanks Mate it now builds and works...however only works for one button. As each button has a different name and different tag number. In the prepareForSegue it only gets buttonOne tag...NSInteger tag = buttonOne.tag;....any ideas?